# How to combine two joins.where in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Help to join the query in one large, well, or grammatically, so that for each company there are dot applications in which

Here are 2 separately working query strings.

```
DotApplication.all.joins(:current_stage_event).where(current_stage_event: {event: "prospect"}).joins('LEFT JOIN tasks on tasks.subject_id = dot_applications.id').where(tasks: {id: nil})

Company.all.joins(:users).where(users: { notification_for_active_prospects: true})
```

What i want:

```
Company.each do |company|
  # For each company(with joins,where above), find all dot_applications as in the examples above
end
```

---

The association between *Company* and *DotApplication* looks like this:

```
# app/models/company.rb
class Comany < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :dot_aplications
end
```

```
# app/models/dot_application.rb
class DotApplication < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
end
```

Comment: What is a relation between `Company` and `DotApplication`? Could you add example with some data

Comment: How can the `tasks.id` be `nil` ? I think you can improve this query a lot!

Comment: @LolWalid This way he gets `dot_applications` with no `tasks`

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-multiple-associations

Comment: I believe [*left_joins*](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-left_joins) is available since Rails 5.0. This would clean up your manual SQL query.

Comment: @JohanWentholt FYI: If not using rails 5 the `includes(:articles).where(articles: {id: 1})` will also generate a left_join. But i don't know if it is something that every body know, I discover it randomly

Comment: @LolWalid Didn't know that, I find it less transparent though. I always thought it generated an inner join instead of an outer join. I mostly use sub-queries for these issues. For example to select all **posts with comments**: `Post.where(id: Comment.select(:post_id))` to select all **posts without comments**: `Post.where.not(id: Comment.select(:post_id))`

Comment: @JohanWentholt Sure it is more readable but when having large database `left joins` might be really faster

Answer (score 0):

You can join on nested associations like this `joins(company: :users)`

In your case this might do the job

```
DotApplication.joins(company: :user).where(users: { notification_for_active_prospects: true})
```

Or full version

```
 DotApplication.all.joins(:current_stage_event, company: :user).where(current_stage_event: {event: "prospect"}).joins('LEFT JOIN tasks on tasks.subject_id = dot_applications.id').where(tasks: {id: nil}).where(users: { notification_for_active_prospects: true})
```

But I really don't recommand you to do this at it is totally unmaintainable

You can read this post of you want to know more about joins https://www.learneroo.com/modules/137/nodes/768

Answer (score 0):

```
Company.joins(:dot_applications)
       .where(dot_appplications: DotApplication.joins(:current_stage_event)
                                               .where(current_stage_event: {event: "prospect"})
                                               .joins('LEFT JOIN tasks on tasks.subject_id = dot_applications.id')
                                               .where(tasks: {id: nil}))
       .joins(:users)
       .where(users: { notification_for_active_prospects: true})
```

This should find all the companies meeting your requirements for the `DotApplication` and then query *those* companies for the `User` requirements